# Intellij 13 and importing an SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I just installed **Intellij 13** and tried importing some basic SBT project. However I received the following error:

[image]

The error message tells that `org.jetbrains#sbt-structure;latest.integration` cannot be found.

I am using SBT 0.13 and everything (compiling, running and etc..) seems to work from the CLI. I have also followed the installation instructions of the `idea-sbt` plugin (https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea).

*build.sbt* that I am using:

```
name := "demo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
```

*project/plugins.sbt*:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.2")
```

Did anyone had this issue and managed to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You don't need sbt-idea plugin, sbt integration should work out of the box (and it worked for the projects I've tried) 2) since it looks more like a bug, not some misconfiguration you probably better to report it to [the bugtracker of scala-idea team](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) (choose scala project when you will fill the ticked)

Comment: oh, [isn't that you](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6361#)?

Comment: @om-nom-nom It appears to be a bug. The solution is to update the Scala plugin to 0.26.323.

Answer (score 2):

This was a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6340) and is resolved in the latest version 0.26.327 (try to run 'Check for Updates...').

If the problem persists, it must be due to another issue but not dependency resolution. In that case you can resort to using the sbt-idea plugin. From a terminal inside your project directory execute `sbt gen-idea`, afterwards you should be able to use 'Open Project...' in IDEA.